# Negative solder mask expansion not working

Tags: altium, solder-mask

I am trying to adjust the solder mask expansion on a component (I can’t change the pad size because of reasons, it is a touch button).

I need the solder mask to be smaller than the footprint.
So I have manually made the solder mask expansion smaller. This works fine down too -1 mm (I can see it becomes smaller).

But if I make it smaller than -1 mm it does not become smaller.
See images. If I make it for example -10 mm it stays the same size.
How come? Does anyone have any idea?

notice in the images that "solder mask expansion" is -1.6 mm vs. -10 mm and they look the same. The purple area is still the same size.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn’t it because of the solder mask expansion design rule? Not sure….